# MyBatis-Spring with Java Config and XML mappers

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I'm setting up a MyBatis project with mybatis-spring, and I'd like to use Java configuration for everything except the actual SQL (e.g. no @Select annotations in the mapper interfaces).

I've got the following setup, which works, but it uses @Select:

**DataSource Beans:**

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource devDataSource() {
        ... set up data source
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**MyBatis Beans:**

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan("myproject.persistence")
public class MyBatisConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        final SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
}
```

**Mapper Interface:**

```
package myproject.persistence;

public interface PersonMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM PersonTable WHERE PersonTable.LAST_NAME = #{lastName}")
    List<Person> getByLastName(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
}
```

**A Service:**

```
@Service
public class PeopleService {

    @Autowired
    PersonMapper personMapper;

    public List<Person> getByLastName(final String lastName) {
        return personMapper.getByLastName(lastName);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to move the SQL statement in the @Select annotation to an XML file (but maintain Java configuration for all beans, and still use @MapperScan). The missing link I'm looking for would be the method to pair the mapper interface with an XML "mapper" that defines SQL statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can define you sql in your PersonMapper.xml under myproject.persistence package (notice:the interface should be in the same package with the xml ).like blow:

```
<mapper namespace="myproject.persistence.PersonMapper">
   <select id="getByLastName" parameterType="string" resultType="myproject.domain.Person">
      SELECT * FROM PersonTable WHERE PersonTable.LAST_NAME = #{lastName}
   </select>
```

mybatis will auto look for the method you defined in the xml files.

Answer (score 2):

```
package cn.fruitd.config;

import com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.AbstractResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Configuration
@MapperScan("cv.fruitd.dao")
public class DBConfig implements EnvironmentAware {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;


    /**
     * 配置数据源
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DruidDataSource dataSource = new DruidDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db-url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db-username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db-password"));
        dataSource.setAsyncInit(Boolean.parseBoolean(env.getProperty("db-asyncInit", "true")));
        dataSource.setMinIdle(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("db-minIdle", "1")));
        dataSource.setMaxActive(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("db-maxActive", "20")));
        dataSource.setMaxWait(Long.parseLong(env.getProperty("db-maxWait", "60000")));
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pathM3R = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setMapperLocations(pathM3R.getResources("classpath*:mybatis/*.xml"));
        return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer() {
        MapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer =
                new MapperScannerConfigurer();
        mapperScannerConfigurer.setBasePackage("cn.fruitd.dao");
        mapperScannerConfigurer.setSqlSessionFactoryBeanName("sqlSessionFactoryBean");
        return mapperScannerConfigurer;
    }


    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.env = environment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more explanation how this code snippet solve the problem defined in the question?